# Simpler way to solve a scenario without cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Lets consider one table

```
Date        Type    TransId     Qty  UnitCost   Total
01/01/2020  OPEN    IN33433     100  12         1200   --IN,UnitCost is fixed
19/03/2020  PUR     IN31134     200  12.5       2500   --IN,UnitCost is fixed
21/03/2020  DEL     OUT24443    250  12.33      3082.5 --OUT unit cost calculated
25/03/2020  DEL     OUT28668    10   12.33      123.3  --OUT unit cost calculated
26/03/2020  SAL     OUT35448    23   12.33      283.59 --OUT unit cost calculated
30/03/2020  TRSFR   IN83588     12   12.45      149.4  --IN, UnitCost is fixed
```

The table depicts an inventory transaction records. Lets say IN types are **OPEN,PUR,TRSFR,ADJIN** and OUT Types are **DEL,SAL,ADJOUT**

Here the Unit cost for all IN transaction are fixed. Which means we will get this value from somewhere and do not need to worry about it.

But for OUT transactions, the unit costs are calculated. For better understanding of the calculation lets consider an example. The first OUT transaction which is on 21/03/2020 with type DEL. The formula for calculating the unitcost for this OUT transaction is:

> sum of all Totals of IN transaction happened before and after any OUT / sum of Qty of all IN transaction happened before  and after any OUT

So the **unitcost=(1200+2500)/(100+200)=12.33**.

And then an IN transaction happened on  30/03/2020 with type TRSFR. For this, as I said earlier the unit cost is fixed. Now for any out transaction happened we will consider the unit cost of 12.45 (149.4/12).

Hope its clear. I need a solution to calculate and get the unit cost without CURSOR. Lets say I need to get the unit cost for a transaction which is supposed to happen on 20/04/2020 of type DEL (which is OUT)

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post a query.

Comment: I have done it with CURSOR but I need to do without it

Comment: Do you want to calculate `UnitCost` for all OUT transactions? Because `Now for any out transaction happened we will consider the unit cost of 12.45 (149.4/12).` confuses like how will you use same value for `OUT` transactions if `OUT` transactions to be calculated.

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: @Surensiveaya First order your results by date descending with row_number() store it in a temp table, then get the least row_number value where you will find any text in  'DEL,SAL,ADJOUT'.

Comment: @Surensiveaya If it is not clear, give me sometime I'll make a query and post as answer.

Comment: @iVad you said "confuses like how will you use same value for OUT transactions if OUT transactions to be calculated". actually for out transacrions value is calculated. Before that out only one IN is there so calculated 12.45 (149.4/12). if there were 2 INs then same calculation (sum of all Totals of IN transaction happened before and after any OUT / sum of Qty of all IN transaction happened before and after any OUT)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using multiple subqueries like below.

```
DECLARE @SampleTable TABLE
(
    Date            DATETIME,
    Type            VARCHAR(100),
    TransId         VARCHAR(100),
    Qty             INT,
    UnitCost        MONEY,
    Total           MONEY
)

INSERT INTO @SampleTable VALUES
('2020-01-01', 'OPEN',  'IN33433',     100 , 12    ,     1200  ), --IN,UnitCost is fixed
('2020-03-19', 'PUR',   'IN31134',     200 , 12.5  ,     2500  ), --IN,UnitCost is fixed
('2020-03-21', 'DEL',   'OUT24443',    250 , 12.33 ,     3082.5), --OUT unit cost calculated
('2020-03-25', 'DEL',   'OUT28668',    10  , 12.33 ,     123.3 ), --OUT unit cost calculated
('2020-03-26', 'SAL',   'OUT35448',    23  , 12.33 ,     283.59), --OUT unit cost calculated
('2020-03-30', 'TRSFR', 'IN83588',     12  , 12.45 ,     149.4 ) --IN, UnitCost is fixed


SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT SUM(Total) FROM @SampleTable S2 WHERE S2.Date < S1.Date AND S2.TransId LIKE 'IN%' AND S1.TransId LIKE 'OUT%') AS SumOutTransaction,
    (SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM @SampleTable S2 WHERE S2.Date < S1.Date AND S2.TransId LIKE 'IN%' AND S1.TransId LIKE 'OUT%') AS SumQtyTransaction,
    CASE
        WHEN S1.TransId LIKE 'OUT%' THEN
                                        (
                                            (SELECT SUM(Total) FROM @SampleTable S2 WHERE S2.Date < S1.Date AND S2.TransId LIKE 'IN%' AND S1.TransId LIKE 'OUT%')
                                            /
                                            (SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM @SampleTable S2 WHERE S2.Date < S1.Date AND S2.TransId LIKE 'IN%' AND S1.TransId LIKE 'OUT%')
                                        )
        ELSE Total/Qty
    END AS CalculatedUnitCost
FROM @SampleTable S1
```

Apart from this, there could be other more optimized options as well.

Comment: Please let me know if you find this helpful. You can accept if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data

```
create table #purchases
(
Date varchar(20),
Type varchar(10),
Transid varchar(100),
Qty int,
UnitCost float,
Total float
)

insert into #purchases values('01/01/2020','OPEN',    'IN33433',     100 , 12     ,    1200)   
insert into #purchases values('19/03/2020','PUR'  ,   'IN31134',     200 , 12.5   ,    2500)   
insert into #purchases values('21/03/2020','DEL'  ,   'OUT24443',    250 , 12.33  ,    3082.5)
insert into #purchases values('25/03/2020','DEL'   ,  'OUT28668',    10  , 12.33  ,    123.3)  
insert into #purchases values('26/03/2020','SAL'   ,  'OUT35448',    23  , 12.33  ,    283.59) 
insert into #purchases values('30/03/2020','TRSFR'  , 'IN83588' ,    12  , 12.45  ,    149.4)
```

Query

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Date desc) as Rn,* into #temp
from #purchases


declare @latestOut int 
select @latestOut=Rn from #temp where  Type in ('DEL','SAL','ADJOUT') order by Rn desc


select SUM(Total)/Sum(Qty) as [Output] from #temp where RN<@latestOut
```